# My mesh flips for a rotation smaller than math.pi

Tags: three.js, rotation, mesh

I am coming back since I am having this geometric problem that I am not familiar with on Unity.
For a f-zero style game, I have a collider box (white on the screen captures) which is the origin of my raycast, and is bound to the movement of the vehicle.
In the shown code, this is this.collider. I control its rotation via a traditional applymatrix and there is no problem.

Then, on top of that, I have the rendered body of the vehicle in this.meshes. It inherits the rotation of the collider box, but gets some extra rotation on its vertical axis to give a visual sliding dynamic during the hard turns. 
It is separate from the collider to keep the vector.forward of the movement (and the raycast) not affected by the extra-rotation. This is purely visual.

My question is: what is the best way to implement it?

I tried different things, but, basically, if I copy the position and rotation of the collider, no problem. As soon as I try to add some extra rotation = this.driftRotation, my body flips when rotation.y value is less than -math.pi. I can adjust the value of the rotation by incrementing  Math.PI (like in Unity), but it doesn't work here.
No clean solution found with applyMatrix neither, and not a lot of google answers on "vertical rotation flip mesh"... though I'm pretty sure this pissue is common.

Some code:

```
this.meshes.position.set(
        this.collider.position.x,
        this.collider.position.y,
        this.collider.position.z);
    this.meshes.rotation.x = this.collider.rotation.x;
    this.meshes.rotation.y = this.collider.rotation.y + this.driftRotation; 
    this.meshes.rotation.z = this.collider.rotation.z;
```

Enclosed more explicit pictures:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I don't see the problem in your screenshots. It looks like on the second frame it's turning right, and on the third one it's turning left, I'm not seeing anything flipping. Are you rotating by more than 90-degrees on multiple axes? You might be running into [gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno). Is it necessary to change y-rotation to `-Pi` instead of keeping it close to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Marquizzo, that's precisely the point: the 3rd px follows the 2nd one, so I'm still turning right but rotation suddenly flips (again, when rotation.y reaches -PI).
Anyway, I fixed it by not trying to directly change rotation.y value, but playing with matrix. Just takes time to understand what does what.

For those who may face a similar pb, here is my temp solution, until I find sthing more performant:

```
    this.meshes.matrix.identity();  
    if (Math.abs(driftAmount) > 0)
    {
        this.driftAxis.copy(this.driftDirection);
        this.driftValue = js.Utils.lerp(this.driftValue, Math.sign(driftAmount) * 0.4, 0.05);
        this.meshes.matrix.makeRotationAxis(this.driftAxis, this.driftValue);
    }
    else if (Math.abs(this.driftValue) > 0)
    {
        this.driftAxis.copy(this.driftDirection);
        this.driftValue = js.Utils.lerp(this.driftValue, 0, 0.1);
        if (Math.abs(this.driftValue) < 0.001)
        {
            this.driftValue = 0;    
        }
        this.meshes.matrix.makeRotationAxis(this.driftAxis, this.driftValue);
    }
    this.meshes.applyMatrix(this.collider.matrix);
```

I had to add a driftAxis along a driftDrection, which is my axis for my vertical rotation.
For ref. I think this subject is +/- bound to the issue I had:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1460

Now I have another issue, how to add another rotation to this.meshes on another axis, the forward one, for a rolling effect, because if I just add another makeRotationAxis in this code it just skips the first one. But that sounds less difficult to figure out, there must exist the equivalent of combineMatrix something...